# WSO2 DAS (3.0.1) cannot connect to google library when starting

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

When starting WSO2 DAS server (3.0.1), there are connection exceptions throwing out as below,

[image: google 1]

[image: google 2]

The DAS server is behind the organization proxy server and I just wonder if I can change some configurations to adapt the proxy server.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 1):

Usually this error is thrown as shindig is trying to load some google analytics apis. But I think this issue was fixed as I couldn't reproduce the same. Can you try the latest DAS version which will be released soon and which is available [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-das/releases/tag/v3.1.0-RC1).

Comment: Thanks your responds. The issue is caused by a proxy server in my organization and resolved it by adding authentication when starting DAS.